# open file.txt and store into variable using argparse

Tags: python, file, input, argparse

how do i have to open file.txt and store the value into 2 variables name inputfileone and inputfiletwo but the error keep confusing me....even file location is true...when i run the command

> python task.py -f fileone.txt -t filetwo.txt

*error = with open(inputfileone, 'r') as fileone:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''*

below is my code...

```
import argparse

#read file from var inputfileone argparse
with open(inputfileone, 'r') as fileone:
      for line in fileone: 
          .....

#read file from var inputfiletwo argparse   
with open(inputfiletwo, 'r') as filetwo:
      for line in filetwo: 


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f","-inputfile1", type=argparse.FileType('r'), help = "file one")
parser.add_argument("-t","-inputfile2", type=argparse.FileType('r'), help = "file two")
args = parser.parse_args()

inputfileone = args.inputfile1 #store value to 'with open(inputfileone, 'r') as fileone:'
inputfiletwo = args.inputfile2
```

Comment: You declare `inputfileone=""`, and then try to open it, meaning you are opening an empty file, which does not exist. Move the `with open` statements to the end.

Comment: @rassar when i remove the inputfileone= "" and inputfiletwo = "". it get error with open(inputfileone, 'r') as fileone:
NameError: name 'inputfileone' is not defined

Comment: Keep the `inputfileone=""` statements. Move the `with open(inputfileone, 'r') as fileone:` statement to after `inputfiletwo = args.inputfile2`.

Comment: When using `FileType`, the parser opens the file for you.  You should not try to open it again with `open(inputfileone)`.  But if you would rather have full control over opening (in the with context), don't use `FileType`; just accept a filename string.

Comment: @hpaulj i remove the filetype in parser.add_argument but it get error with open(inputfileone, 'r') as fileone:
NameError: name 'inputfileone' is not defined

Comment: Wait until after the `parse_args()` to use the file;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileType` opens the file for you; don't try it again:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f","-inputfile1", type=argparse.FileType('r'), help = "file one")
parser.add_argument("-t","-inputfile2", type=argparse.FileType('r'), help = "file two")
args = parser.parse_args()

inputfileone = args.inputfile1   # file is already open
inputfiletwo = args.inputfile2 

#read file from var inputfileone
for line in fileone: 
          .....
```

alternative:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f","-inputfile1", help = "file one")
parser.add_argument("-t","-inputfile2", help = "file two")
args = parser.parse_args()

inputfileone = args.inputfile1   # plain filename
inputfiletwo = args.inputfile2 

#read file from var inputfileone
with open(inputfileone, 'r') as fileone:
     for line in fileone: 
         .....
```

In both cases, wait until after the `parse_args` to use the `inputfileone` variable.

====

A better script organization:

```
import argparse

def read_file1(filename):
    with  open(filename) as f:
        ...
def create_parser():
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument("-f","--inputfile1")
     ...
     return parser           

if __name__ == '__main__':
     parser = create_parser()
     args = parser.parse_args()
     filename1 = args.inputfile1
     read_file1(filename1)
     ....
```